# Bash redirection help

Tags: bash

I'm having a little issue getting quite a simple bash script running.

The part that's working:

```
qstat -f $queuenum | grep -Po '(?<=PBS_O_WORKDIR=).*(?=,)'
```

Outputs a directory to the screen (for example):

> /short/h72/SiO2/defected/2-999/3-forces/FORCES_364

All I want to do is change directory to this folder. Appending a "| cd" to the end of the above command doesn't work, and I can't quite figure out how to use the $(()) tags either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd `qstat -f $queuenum | grep -Po '(?<=PBS_O_WORKDIR=).*(?=,)' `
```

Comment: That's something I've tried already too. I get no errors if I attempt this, but I don't actually change directories. Do I need to escape the variable somehow for this to work?

Comment: @Geodesic: You can use `.` to force the script to run in the current shell, i.e. `. ./my_script.sh`.

Comment: also, using double quote around the directory (`cd "$(qstat ...)"`) will work even if the directory name contains spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking your script creates a new `bash` shell

This shell is destroyed when your script ends.

If you use `exec <scriptname>` to run your script, the new `bash` shell is substituted for the current one. So if you add the command `bash` at the end of your script, you will get what you desire, but not the same `bash` shell.

Comment: I see. That certainly works, but isn't really the best solution. I use my history a lot so I'd prefer not to start a new shell. Any ideas on how to do that? I didn't think this issue would be a bash limitation.

Comment: maybe using `source scriptname` could be better, executing the script in the current shell, without substituting it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
cd "$(qstat -f $queuenum | grep -Po '(?<=PBS_O_WORKDIR=).*(?=,)' )"
```

you are trying to achieve command substitution which is achieved by using either of these two syntax:

```
$(command)
```

or like this using backticks:

```
`command`
```

The first one is the preferred way as it allows nesting of command substitutions something like:

```
foo=$(command1 | command2 $(command3))
```

also you should enclose the entire command substitution in double quotes to protect you if the result of the command substitution is a string with spaces.